# Activity Camera (in application Camera) is not responding

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, camera

I am having a strange issue with my Camera app.  When I open the application, I received the following message:

```
Activity Camera (in application Camera) is not responding
```

after about 5 seconds.  However, I am able to capture photos from Facebook using the Camera activity, and other photo apps like Camera 360 works properly as well.

I have Samsung Galaxy S2 (GT-I1900) from AT&T.

**Edit**

Thing I have tried:

- Clear cache/data from Settings/Application/Manage Application/Camera
- Remove SD card, which results in the error "Please insert an SD card
  before using the camera."
- Restoring the Camera Apps from Titaniumn Backup from 2 weeks ago, when the Camera app was working.

Comment: Have you tried to clear data for the camera app?